# JFrame Shows What's Behind It

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

[image: JFrame Problem Image]

```
    JFrame newLineFrame = new JFrame();
    JPanel newLinePanel = new JPanel();
    newLineFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    newLineFrame.setSize(500, 500);
    newLineFrame.setResizable(false);
    newLineFrame.setVisible(true);
    newLinePanel.setOpaque(true);
    newLinePanel.add(new JLabel("Hello"));
    newLineFrame.add(newLinePanel);
    newLineFrame.repaint();
```

Above is a small section of my code that creates a new JFrame. Instead of the showing the JLabel, the JFrame just shows what is behind it when it is created.

Does anyone know why this is and how I can resolve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're overriding `paint` or `paintComponent` and not calling `super.paintXxx`? As much as I would love to play "guess what's wrong with my code", you're better off providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I just tried to recreate the problem without using the entirety of my code, but for some reason it worked perfectly! I'll post some runnable code of the problem as soon as I can...

Answer (score 0):

`JFrame` shows his components contents. You are adding a component to a `JFrame`, inside what it really does's adding it to your `contentPane` which's a `JPanel`, and afterwards you are adding a different `JPanel`.
I am not sure if that's the cause of your problems but that must be wrong. Instead, do this:

```
    JFrame newLineFrame = new JFrame();
    JPanel newLinePanel = new JPanel();
    newLineFrame.setContentPane(newLinePanel);
    newLineFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    newLineFrame.setSize(500, 500);
    newLineFrame.setResizable(false);
    newLineFrame.setVisible(true);
    newLinePanel.setOpaque(true);
    newLinePanel.add(new JLabel("Hello"));        
    newLineFrame.repaint();
```

Try it and let me know if it works :)

Comment: Since 1.5 (I believe), `JFrame#add` defers automatically to the content pane (making it equivalent to `JFrame#getContentPane#add`)

Comment: Thanks but @MadProgrammer was right and it made no difference. Any other ideas?

Comment: @LouisSlater *"Any other ideas?"* - Providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I am testing it myself and I am afraid it is working. So, @MadProgrammer is right about the fact that we need more code to find out what's going on.